# Gatsby featuredImage query with childImageSharp: Field must not have a selection error

Tags: image, graphql, gatsby

I really need some help...
I'm currently building a site with Gatsby. I'm struggling to query the featured image that will appear on each post...
The front matter of the post is defined as follows.

```
---
title: Configuration 1
date: "2015-05-01T22:12:03.284Z"
description: "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue;"
featuredImage: gatsby-banner.png
slug: _1
---.
```

The markdown file and the featured image file are in the same path.
From the root path, There are markdown files and a featured image file inside "content/blog/categoreis/gatsby".

In src/templates, I have the blog-post.tsx file, and the component is querying the front matter as follows.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostBySlug(
    $id: String!
    $previousPostId: String
    $nextPostId: String
  ) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      excerpt(pruneLength: 160)
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        description
        featuredImage {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
    previous: markdownRemark(id: { eq: $previousPostId }) {
      fields {
        slug
      }
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
    next: markdownRemark(id: { eq: $nextPostId }) {
      fields {
        slug
      }
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

But when I did this, I kept getting the following error

"Field "featuredImage" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields."

Some sites said that I should modify the type of the frontmatter in the `gatsby-node.js` file to fix this, so I did that as well, and now the frontmatter's type in `gatsby-node.js` is as follows.

```
type MarkdownRemark implements Node {
      frontmatter: Frontmatter
      fields: Fields
    }

    type Frontmatter {
      title: String
      description: String
      date: Date @dateformat
      featuredImage: FeaturedImage
    }

    type FeaturedImage {
      childImageSharp: ImageSharp
    }

    type ImageSharp {
      gatsbyImageData: GatsbyImageData
    }
```

I modified it as above and queried it with GraphQL, but in the browser, I get undefined, and in GraphQL, I still get "Field "featuredImage" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields." error message. I really need some help...

Here is my github repository url.
https://github.com/engulfedInFlames/my_gatsby_blog